# Pressing F5 (Debug) in Visual Studio 2013 works, but deletes a character

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

For example:

```
comboCategory.DisplayMember = "Name"; //Cursor here
comboCategory.DataSource = context.Category.ToList();
```

Then i press F5, the program builds and runs, but i get:

```
comboCategory.DisplayMember = "Name"; comboCategory.DataSource = context.Category.ToList();
```

etc in every situation, where should i start to investigate?

Comment: I would start with disabling extension.

Comment: I have exactly the same setup of extensions on my machine at work...i am having the problem at my personal laptop. It's a Lenovo Y510P if it matters.

Comment: I disabled the extensions and even uninstalled them completely but to no avail.